# "The network path was not found" error after renamin the domain

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

After renaming the domain on windows 2008, I cannot join the clients to server.
The previous domain was "uoidm.org" and the new one is "kalhori.org".
I renamed the domain using rendom.exe and the domain renamed correctly.
Then I created a DNS zone for the new domain but the problem is every time i attempt to join new  clients the following error occurs:
"The network path was not found"
What's the problem?
There's zone named "_msdcs.uoidm.org" in Forward Lookup Zone and i suspicious about it.
How can I change it to "_msdcs.kalhori.org"?
Is this problem related to a bad DNS configuration?
How can i configure the DNS to resolve this problem?
I'm a newbie and don't understands these issues so please help and give me a step by step solution.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow all of the items on the [checklist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816631%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for renaming a 2008 domain? Specifically, running the operation from a member server, not a DC?

You should also have [prepared](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794811%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) the DNS zone before the rename operation. Did you do this, or did you just go ahead and run rendom without the prep work?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Chris McKeown.
I run rendom from server computer but there was not any problem during the operatinos.
After renamin domain I created a zone for new domain too. I'm afraid of "_msdcs.uoidm.org" zone. should i change it to "_msdcs.kalhori.org"? is this the problem?

Comment: You should have prepared the domain before you ran rendom - as per the checklists in the links I provided. To be honest I'm not sure how you'd recover from the situation you're now in.

Answer (score -1):

IS "full computer name" of the dc server correct? if not edit it manually, to do that, open **system properties**, **computer name** tab, **change** button, **more** button, and change "**primary DNS suffix of this computer**".

regards, Mona